# Change MediaController position on rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

I'm trying to change `MediaController`'s anchor dynamically on orientation changes. And after all my attempts this isn't working as needed.

Perhaps you could point out my mistake.

*In a few words:*

**Portrait mode:**

1. weightSum = 1.
2. `SurfaceView` weight: 0.4
3. `MediaController` and `HorizontalScrollView` weight: 0.6
4. `MediaController` always visible and not hiding

**Landscape mode:**

1. `SurfaceView` weight: 0.0 (full screen)
2. `MediaControlls` = `View.Gone` (I need to change its anchor to `SurfaceView`. And popup onTouch. But how??)

---

*CODE CODE:*

**player.xml:**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context="tenkol.design.com.imbrecords.ActivityExoPlayer"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surface_wrapper"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer.VideoSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/shutter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/controls_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
        </FrameLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/myGallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/channelsScrollView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**code with transformation:**

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (Global.getScreenOrientation(this) == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //hide action bar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        if (myGallery != null) {
            //hide HorizontalScrollView
            myGallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        //make surface fullscreen
        surfaceWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0f));
        controlsWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0f));
        //hide mediaController
        mc.hide();
        controlsWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (Global.getScreenOrientation(this) == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //and here restore everything
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        if (myGallery != null) {
            myGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        surfaceWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0.4f));
        controlsWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.6f));
        controlsWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**What I tried:**

1) When Landscape: create another mediaController and bind to root view(doesn't work):

```
  mediaController.setAnchorView(root);
  mediaController.setMediaPlayer(player.getPlayerControl());
  mediaController.setEnabled(true);
  mediaController.show(3);
```

2) When Landscape: change the anchor of previous `MediaController` (Nah).

```
  mc.setAnchorView(surfaceWrapper);
  mc.show(3);
```

3) interface `surfaceChanged` (still no):

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if (Global.getScreenOrientation(this) == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        mc.setAnchorView(surfaceWrapper);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(player.getPlayerControl());
        mc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mc.show(3);
    }
}
```

So how can I change the `MediaController`'s anchor to `SurfaceView` dynamically in `LANDSCAPE` mode?

*P.S.* Tell if some more code needed.

Comment: @prudhvi, Unfortunately no. But I solved this in a bit tricky way. I've created 2 `MediaControllers` which act like one and set different anchors for them. And the trick was in hiding one of them when orientation changes. So in landscape mode I had controlled linked to `VideoSurface` and in portrait mode controller was anchored to `LinearLayout` with buttons and stuff.

Comment: Are you doing this in conjunction with the standard Android MediaPlayer?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, I was using Google Exo Player as far as I remember. But it's quite similar to standard one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're overriding onConfigurationChanged, I assume that means the activity is not allowing Android to manage its orientation changes and instead choosing to do everything itself.  This is normally not a great idea, and you're currently facing the pain of that decision.  :-(

If I may make a recommendation: let Android manage the lifecycle of your activity, and use different layouts (e.g. layout-land/views.xml and layout-port/views.xml).  This will allow you to express your layouts naturally in the XML without having to make crazy code changes.

You probably about to say: But I want my ExoPlayer not to have to stop, prepare and restart on every orientation change.  The good news is that there is a way to work around this.

Just create a single ExoPlayer, prepare it at first load, and keep using that one instance (stored in a static or some other singleton) with each new activity instance.  You can detach the old activity from it and reattach a new one when it's ready.

If ExoPlayer works similarly to MediaPlayer, then this should all work OK.